# How we can put some custom button in UWP Mapcontrol?

Tags: xaml, uwp

How we can put some custom button in UWP Mapcontrol ?
like below picture ?

[image: Sample in mobile]

Comment: Why don't you place these button in Parent Grid?

Comment: because of some extra functionality that need in map , it's a design approach for better user experience

Comment: What do you mean by "some extra functionality"? You can make the exact design as show in your sample image

Comment: thank you , how can we put some additional button in MapControl ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your parent `Grid` to place buttons on `MapControl`

**Sample code:**

```
<Grid Width="400" Height="400">
    <Maps:MapControl Width="400" Height="400"/>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,20,20,0">
        <SymbolIcon Symbol="Add"/>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

**Sample output:**

[image]